# Security of email OTP authentication

Tags: authentication, one-time-password

I'm building my own authentication and deciding on the signup/login flow. I'm would like some security feedback on this type of flow:

1. User submits email address.
2. 6 character alphanumeric one-time-code is generated and sent to the provided email. OTP is saved in database along with the email and an expiration (5 min).
3. User enters code and is logged in. User is created if does not exist.

Is this bad security-wise? Am I missing something? I'm thinking the OTP has an expiration of 5 minutes and maximum 3 failed attempts before revoked. Is 6 characters enough?

Auth0 seems to have this as well:
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/guides/email-otp

Comment: Can you explain little more about your requirement?

Comment: Other sites are not using a OTP verification but a link that is sent to the users email. You can verify your address by clicking on the link.

Comment: My idea was to use an OTP for logging in, then there’s no need to verify the email. Also no need to handle password resets etc.

Comment: @Infra - what kind of info do you need?

Comment: I want to know your requirement. Then we can decide flow is feasible or not. If you are not verify mean, I can use tool and generate miilions of fake email and create accounts on your applications.

Comment: The OTP code will be sent to the email address. If you have access to the code you have access to the email = it’s verified.

Comment: @Richard, I read it wrong way. However ever you are still vulnerable to DDOS because of this setup. Your security Mechanism should be based on data and information you are going to handle.... Additionally Below answer provides comprehensive details.

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** *User submits email address*. How is this email address submitted, is it via a secured HTTPs web interface?

**(2)** *one-time-code is sent to the provided email*. Although commonly done for initialization, e-mail is NOT a secure transport mechanism. Emailing access codes for every login is asking for trouble.

I'll also note that some email providers can be quite slow on distribution and 5 minutes may be insufficient.

You are also creating an easy DoS resource exhaustion by maintaining state data for every attempt.

It also becomes a reflection attack platform against others. I can automate a few thousand (*million*) CEO@company.com requests and have your system bury someone's email.

Fundamentally you're using insecure credential transport to avoid using a secure login.

Comment: Thanks! The email address will always be submitted with https. Based on your concerns regarding the email transport I guess you don’t find “magic links” any better? A one-time link sent to the user’s email. Thats a very common auth flow these days.

Comment: @Richard - Magic links would be the same concern. Consider why you are working so hard to cobble together an alternative to a simple logon. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: But would you really say that's a bigger security issue than what we have with email/password? Users reusing the same password on different sites, choosing passwords that are easy to guess. Not to mention having to support password reset and email verification that still relies on access to an email account. I believe there's a reason why "passwordless" is being more and more common.

Comment: @Richard - It sounds like what you really want is 2FA to ameliorate poor user choices. Maybe something like **Authy**  https://authy.com/.

Comment: Eh no, not at all. That’s a totally different thing. Forcing 2FA has major UX implications and is a completely separate discussion.

Comment: @Richard Magic links are dangerous because a lot of anti-malware e-mail gateways automatically check each contained link in an email and thus automatically "click" on them. Therefore such links can get executed without any user interaction.